# How can I allow uppercase letter with sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

How can I allow on the following regex the uppercase letters?

Regex is perfectly fine, but it will also rename it if there is uppercase letters on it and I want to allow it.

```
renamed_file="$(echo "$filename" | sed -e 's/[A-Z]/\L&/g' -e 's/[^a-z0-9]/_/g')"
```

Comment: please provide a complete example, including the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your regex in `sed` as followed,

```
sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9]/_/g'
```

In this way, any character that doesn't match to `A-Za-z0-9` would be converted to `_`